# Get item based on displayname in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I need to get a specific item based on it's displayname, how do I do that?

For example I want to get this item /sitecore/content/mysite/about 
But on the site is translated to multiple languages and could be something like www.site.com/om (in Sitecore it would be /sitecore/content/mysite/om)

Comment: Hi.. when you say you want to get a item you mean using the API, in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple approaches you can take. The most efficent is to leverage the Content Search API, but the challenge is that Display Name is excluded from the index by default. A simple patch file can fix this:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
          <exclude>
            <__display_name>
              <patch:delete />
            </__display_name>
          </exclude>
        </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then your code would be something like:

```cs
public Item GetItemByDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    var searchIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index"); // sub your index name
    using (var context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var searchResultItems =
            context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => i["Display Name"].Equals(displayName)).FirstOrDefault();


        return searchResultItems == null ? null : searchResultItems.GetItem();
    }
}
```

This all is assuming you are on Sitecore 7. If you're on Sitecore 6, your option are limited and are probably not going to perform well if you content tree is large. Nonetheless, your function might look like:

```cs
public Item GetItemByDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__Display Name='{0}']", displayName);

    var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem(query);

    return item;
}
```

Please note that this will be horribly inefficent since under the covers this is basically walking the content tree.

Comment: Is there anyway we can include the template name to make it more refined ?

Comment: what about if my display name with space? It is unable to use as search key word.

Answer (score 1):

Often, you wouldn't need to. LinkManager (responsible for generating all your item URLs) has an option to base the URLs on Display Name instead of Item.Name.

```
        var d = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
        d.UseDisplayName = true;
```

This can also be configured in configuration. Find and amend this section in your Web.config (or patch it via include files):

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
        addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true"
        languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" 
        shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

To truly do exactly what you ask is a quite involved process. If you point DotPeek to Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, you can step through the ResolveUsingDisplayName() method. It essentially loops through child items, comparing the URL Part to the "__Display Name" field. You would have to cook up something similar.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have done, generate urls based on the display name.

It gets even more tricky because it's a webservice being called on the page and it knows nothing of Sitecore, only the url it's called from (sitecore item with display name) so I have to backtrack to a specific item based on a url.

But thanks for input, I will try to figure something out.